# Angular JS error while loading resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to load this controller:

```
.controller('UserEditController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,User){

  $scope.updateUser=function(){
      $scope.user.$update(function(){
          $state.go('users');
      });
  };

  $scope.loadUser=function(){
      $scope.user=User.get({id:$stateParams.id});
  };

  $scope.loadUser();
});
```

I get this error in Chrome:

`Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array&p3=GET&p4=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fusers`

Comment: maybe your resource is returning an array instead of an object?

Comment: The issue seems to be in the User service. Please share that piece of code too.

Comment: @DavidFigueroa heres the service:
https://jsfiddle.net/javiroberts/to5dg0ta/

Comment: @JaviRoberts You're passing in a function instead of an object in the $update call, inside updateUser

Comment: @anpatel and how should i pass the object?

Comment: @JaviRoberts User.update($scope.user) should work since get returns an object, and i think you're editing $scope.user

Comment: If you want to move states after the update, I would use the $promise attribute of the update call and do a .then(function() { }) and inside that do the state.go

Comment: I don't think you're having an issue with the update, at least not at this point. 
Your `$resource` call to `http://localhost:3000/api/users/:id` is probably retrieving an array instead of the expected object.
You'll have to change the response from the server.

Comment: @DavidFigueroa i checked the response and the call returns an object

Answer (score 1):

Try to use query instead of get:

```
$scope.user = User.query({id:$stateParams.id});
```